# IIS URL Rewrite Redirect Language difficulties

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, redirect

I'm trying to redirect pages on a site who don't exist anymore to another page.
The problem is with the 3 languages we built our site in. I've created 3 rules.

1. To redirect without the language in the url (works perfectly!)
2. To redirect with the language "en":

   ```html
   <rule name="Redirect &quot;en&quot;" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="(.*)/([a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
   <add input="{Redirects:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
   </conditions>
   <action type="Redirect" url="{R:2}{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" />
   </rule>
   ```
3. To redirect with the languages "nl-be" and "fr-be":

   ```html
   <rule name="Redirect &quot;nl-be&quot;/&quot;fr-be&quot;" stopProcessing="true">
   <match url="/([a-zA-Z]{2}\-[a-zA-Z]{2})/(.*)" />
   <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true" />
   <action type="Redirect" url="/{R:1}/{C:1}" />
   </rule>
   ```

They should all use the same rewrite maps, just copy over the language-part of the url.
This is an example of the rewrite map:

```html
<rewriteMaps>
<rewriteMap name="Redirects">
<add key="/maptest" value="/flights" />
</rewriteMap>
</rewriteMaps>
```

I hope you guys can help me.

greetings, and thnx in advance!